# Use jQuery to replace form params with a JSON object on submit

Tags: jquery

How would you code the function replaceFormParamsWithJsonObject(jsonObject)?

```
$('#myForm').submit(replaceFormParamsWithJsonObject(jsonObject));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're after but something like this?

```
$.each(jsonObject, function(key, value)
{
    $(this).find('input:[name=' + key + ']').val(value);
});
```

This will update the form inputs with names corresponding to  the object's keys.